# Android webview Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 in tid (ThreadPoolForeg)

Tags: android, cordova, webview, architecture, crash

Try to load url in web view, crashing after some time. It happens in Android 7.1 devices.

**Code :**

```
private SystemWebView syswvViewDocuments;
private CordovaWebView wvViewDocuments;

wvViewDocuments = new CordovaWebViewImpl(new SystemWebViewEngine(syswvViewDocuments));
wvViewDocuments.init((CordovaInterface) getParentFragment(), parser.getPluginEntries(), parser.getPreferences());

syswvViewDocuments = view.findViewById(R.id.wvViewDocuments);
WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
syswvViewDocuments.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
syswvViewDocuments.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
syswvViewDocuments.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
syswvViewDocuments.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
syswvViewDocuments.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);


wvViewDocuments.loadUrl(url);           

SystemWebViewEngine systemWebViewEngine = (SystemWebViewEngine) wvViewDocuments.getEngine();
mDocumentViewClient = new DocumentViewClient(systemWebViewEngine, getParentFragment(), (CordovaInterface) getParentFragment(), wvViewDocuments, mActivity, this, bundle);
syswvViewDocuments.setWebViewClient(mDocumentViewClient);
if (ApplicationStore.isUsingNativeFileChooser()) {
    syswvViewDocuments.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient(systemWebViewEngine, (CordovaInterface) getParentFragment(), mActivity, getParentFragment()));
}
```

**Device detail:**

`htc Nexus 9
OS 7.1.1
ABI : arm64-v8a
API : 25`

**Working fine when:**

```
defaultConfig {
    ndk {       
         abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
    }
}
```

**Crashing when:**

```
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86_64", "x86"
    }
}
```

**Error code**

`2019-08-09 13:14:56.699 12289-12889/com.test.example E/v8: #
    # Fatal error in , line 0
    # 
2019-08-09 13:14:56.699 12289-12889/com.test.example E/v8: ignored
2019-08-09 13:14:56.699 12289-12889/com.test.example E/v8: #
    #
    #
    #FailureMessage Object: 0x7653f00980
2019-08-09 13:14:57.475 12289-12889/com.test.example A/libc: Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 in tid 12889 (ThreadPoolForeg)`

Full Crash report

```
2019-08-09 18:59:24.132 7226-7294/? A/libc: Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 in tid 7294 (ThreadPoolForeg)
2019-08-09 18:59:24.187 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2019-08-09 18:59:24.188 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/volantis/flounder:7.1.1/N9F27M/4333998:user/release-keys'
2019-08-09 18:59:24.188 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2019-08-09 18:59:24.188 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2019-08-09 18:59:24.188 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: pid: 7226, tid: 7294, name: ThreadPoolForeg >>> com.asite.Adoddle <<<
2019-08-09 18:59:24.188 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT), fault addr 0x766c15e768
2019-08-09 18:59:24.188 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: x0 0000000000000000 x1 0000000000000000 x2 0000000000000000 x3 0000000000000003
2019-08-09 18:59:24.188 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: x4 0000000000000000 x5 0000000000000000 x6 0000007682b23000 x7 0000000000000000
2019-08-09 18:59:24.188 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: x8 0000000000000001 x9 0000000000000001 x10 0000000000004001 x11 0000000000000000
2019-08-09 18:59:24.188 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: x12 0000000000000018 x13 0000000000000000 x14 0000000000000000 x15 00197a22b6e4b5d7
2019-08-09 18:59:24.188 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: x16 000000768204e440 x17 0000007681ff9ccc x18 0000000000015180 x19 00000076693a2587
2019-08-09 18:59:24.188 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: x20 00000076820507c8 x21 ffffff80ffffffc8 x22 0000007659951c00 x23 0000007659951900
2019-08-09 18:59:24.188 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: x24 0000007659951940 x25 00000073b64ef218 x26 00000073b4da46bc x27 00000073b4c5a428
2019-08-09 18:59:24.188 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: x28 00000000fffffbf8 x29 0000007659951bf0 x30 000000766c15d160
2019-08-09 18:59:24.188 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: sp 0000007659951880 pc 000000766c15e768 pstate 0000000080000000

2019-08-09 18:59:24.191 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2019-08-09 18:59:24.196 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: #00 pc 0000000002ff9768 /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk (offset 0xc0f000)
2019-08-09 18:59:24.196 8393-8393/? A/DEBUG: #01 pc 0000000002ff815c /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk (offset 0xc0f000)
```